# Algorithm timing in Python

Tags: python

I want to compute how many times my computer can do `counter += 1` in one second. A naive approach is the following:

```
from time import time

counter = 0
startTime = time()

while time() - startTime < 1:
    counter += 1

print counter
```

The problem is `time() - startTime < 1` may be considerably more expensive than `counter += 1`.

Is there a way to make a less "clean" 1 sec sample of my algorithm?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual way to time algorithms is the other way around:  Use a fixed number of iterations and measure how long it takes to finish them.  The best way to do such timings is the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module.

```
print timeit.timeit("counter += 1", "counter = 0", number=100000000)
```

Note that timing `counter += 1` seems rather pointless, though.  What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm globally interested in how many operations per second my computer can handle, which is a slightly different problem.

Comment: @Randomblue: "Operations per second" isn't to well-defined a notion.  And a Python-script certainly isn't the right way to test the speed of a processor.

Comment: @Randomblue if you really want to do it the other way around, measure how many "operations" it can do within an hour and divide it by 3600.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you infer the time instead? You can run something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

def operation():
    counter = 0
    tbeg = datetime.utcnow()
    for _ in range(10**6):
        counter += 1
    td = datetime.utcnow() - tbeg
    return (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6)/10.0**6

def timer(n):
    stack = []
    for _ in range(n):        
        stack.append(operation()) #  units of musec/increment
    print sum(stack) / len(stack)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    timer(10)
```

and get the average elapsed microseconds per increment; I get 0.09 (most likely very inaccurate). Now, it is a simple operation to infer that if I can make one increment in 0.09 microseconds, then I am able to make about 11258992 in one second.

I think the measurements are very inaccurate, but maybe is a sensible approximation?

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with the time() library, but according to that code I assume it counts seconds, so what if you do the /sec calculations after ctrl+C happens? It would be something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from time import time
import signal
import sys

#The ctrl+C interruption function:
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    counts_per_sec = counter/(time()-startTime)
    print counts_per_sec
    exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

counter = 0
startTime = time()
while 1:
    counter = counter + 1
```

Of course, it wont be exact because of the time passed between the last second processed and the interruption signal, but the more time you leave the script running, the more precise it will be :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach

```
import time

m = 0
timeout = time.time() + 1 

while True:
    if time.time() > timeout:
        break
    m = m + 1
print(m)
```